# How to trigger a Jenkins pipeline once a Bitbucket pipeline is finished?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket

I have the following requirement. I have a Jenkins pipeline which I want to be triggered once a Bitbucket pipeline has been finished with success. The problem is that I need to pass also some params and I don't want to use an asynchronous process like Bitbucket webhooks.
Is it another way to trigger the Jenkins pipeline automatically receiving multiple params?

I want to mention that these params can be retrieved also from the AWS resources created by that Bitbucket pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, but i found a solution using **Additional Behaviours**
from git plugin.
Using [Polling ignores commits with certain messages](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-polling-ignores-commits-with-certain-messages), which allow you to:

> ignore any revisions committed with message matched to the regular expression pattern when determining if a build needs to be triggered.

and am using `[skip ci]` int the commit message, to commit changes after Bit-bucket pipeline finished.
so i used a custom regex `^(?!.*\[skip ci\]).*$` to skip any commit not including the tag.
which will result to **only** **trigger Jenkins once the pipeline finished**.